# How do I read out the first 4 bytes in javascript, turn it into an integer and remove the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to transfer webcam data over the internet from one browser to another.

The webcam is displayed in a `HTML5 canvas`. Then I get its dataUrl, and turn it into a `blob`. Then I send this blob to my server.

From what I understand, the blob is essentially a `byte array`. I've converted it to a byte array on the server-side, it has the same length as `blob.size` in the browser, so that seems fine. I need to add a sender id to it, so I convert an integer to an array of `4 bytes` and add it to the front of the byte array.

Now I need to send this modified blob to the other browser. And this is where I'm confused.

1. How do I read out the first 4 bytes in javascript and turn it into an integer again?
2. And how do I cut off the rest of the blob?

Comment: use the `parseInt(someInt, base);` for turning 4bytes into an integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Blob.slice() method to get bytes.
See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice

1)

```
var bytes = blob.slice(0,4);
```

2)

```
var arrayOfBytes = [];
for(var i=0;i<blob.size/4;i++){
    arrayOfBytes[i] = blob.slice(i*4,4+(i*4));
}
```

Note: **I didn't test it!**

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thanks a lot. I'll try that and accept your answer after I could validate!

Comment: Excuse me, if `blob.slice(0,4)` gives me the first 4 bytes of the blob, couldn't I just use `blob.slice(4,blob.size-1`) to get the rest?

I don't quite understand your 2)

Comment: @spacecoyote Sure, you can. But if you want to receive a full amount of bytes don't  pass last parameter: `blob.slice(4)` Second param is default size of the blob