# Posting URL-encoded file data with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, filereader

Is it possible to do this? In more detail:

1. I have a file object which I have retrieved from an input element
2. I want to upload this to the server, together with a couple of
   key/value pairs with related data (file name, and so on)
3. I want to do this with Ajax, because everthing else in the system
   uses Ajax, and I have standardised success/fail handling based on
   the server response
4. I want to do this with URL encoding, because the file is small, and
   the server doesn't implement `multipart/form-data`

I've tried several different things, but none of them is quite right. This code sends the file data 'as-is' (ie. effectively raw binary, and not as a URL-encoded key-value pair):

```
   var files = document.getElementById('idUploadBrowseInput').files;
   var fdata = files[0];
   var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      type        : "POST",
      url         : "/cgi-bin/upload_cgi",
      timeout     : 20000,
      processData : false,
      data        : fdata
   }).always(...etc)
```

Raw binary would be Ok, but I also need the other key-value pairs, and it doesn't seem to be possible to send these at the same time.

If I change the `data : fdata` line to `data : {fdata : fdata}` then the POST data just becomes `[object Object]` (on FF). If I remove the `processData:false` then I get an exception in jQuery.

The FileReader API has some `readAs` methods which I guess I should be using - presumably, if I read the file contents into a `var`, then I can just send the var as part of the data object and it should all just work. However, this is long-winded, and I just want to check that there isn't a more direct way of doing this first.

Note that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399484/posting-file-input-as-filereader-binary-data-through-ajax-post) doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Not certain, please clarify requirement ? Thanks

Comment: In short, when using Ajax, can you send a URL-encoded file 'object' as a key-value pair, together with other key-value pairs?

Comment: If possible, can post `cgi` pieces ? Please clarify `object` ? Tried `file` `object` as `base64` string ? or `encodeURIComponent(file)` ? Try `Blob` and `FileReder` ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140007/how-do-i-read-out-the-first-4-bytes-in-javascript-turn-it-into-an-integer-and-r

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to send a file using AJAX (and jQuery), there are even 2 different ways of doing it:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload'); // refers to <input type="file">
const file = fileInput.files[0];

let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function () {
  console.log(reader.result);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/file-upload',

    // data: { file: reader.result }, // #1

    // data: reader.result,           // #2
    // processData: false,

    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
}

// reader.readAsBinaryString(file); // #1
// reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);  // #2
```

The first method sends URL-encoded version of the file. On the server side it looks like this:

```
POST /file-upload HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 59577
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.116
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

file=%00%00%00%02%00%00%00%C3%89%5B%C3%B1%15Y%2B%C3%86%C2%82%04%5C%0A%C2%...
```

The second method sends the file in it's raw form - the whole content is pure binary data:

```
POST /file-upload HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12342
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.116
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

É[ñY+Æ\»H*|UÌ¤FÝ▒§®Y3NÙ+2¤"ã0èT...
```

Note the `Content-Length` field - the raw form is definitely more optimal but it doesn't let you conveniently send any other key-value pair data like the first form.